# Kentia Palm (Howea Forsteriana) is drying out

Tags: leaves, watering, plant-care

I bought this Howea Forsteriana less than 1 month ago. I water it around each 7/10 days, spray some water on leaves every day, often twice a day. It used to be in front of a north west window, when I saw this change I though it was too much light and for the last 4 days I moved it around 1ft far from the same window.

I am searching for any kind of information but I am not sure the reason of this issues I am having.

Thanks for any indication
Giorgio

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it planted in a pot which has drainage holes? It doesn't look as if it is...

Comment: @Bamboo you are right. There is no drainage holes. The pot is not flat at the bottom, it has three kind of legs so that the roots didn't reach the bottom in case of too much water. I am alway careful not to water too much the plant and wait for the soil to be dry at least 2 inches

Comment: Get it into a pot with drainage holes - water thoroughly when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, empty out any outer tray or pot after thirty minutes.